# Dynamically created regex Java

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to force my test app to create regex dynamically. Is there any way to make it work? I'm asking because I've tried with the `Pattern.quote()` method, but it had no effect at all.

I put my regex in String variable of course. It looks like:

```
String pattern = "src=\\\"([^\\\"])*\\\\.((jpg)|(png)|(gif))\\\"";
```

Comment: Pattern.compile(your string value) every time you change the contents of the string...

Comment: Pattern.quote makes regex be interpreted verbatim, i.e. it makes your string to be a non-regex.

Comment: The thing is, that I've keep file expressions in enum type and pattern have to be created why app is runing.

Comment: Ok, I've done it. I had a short brainstorm. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Matt_DontKnow patterns are *always* created while the app is running.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know. I'm sorry for this, I'm a bit tired. Thanks to all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra "\" from the constructed pattern and use `Pattern.compile` and `Pattern.matcher`

```
       String pattern = "src=\"([^\"])*\\.((jpg)|(png)|(gif))\"";                  
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
       Matcher m = p.matcher("src=\"abc.png\"");
       if (m.matches()){
           System.out.println("Found  " + m.group());
       }
```